# Interrupt User action with Oauth login with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, omniauth

Thanks to all in advance.

I'm looking to hide a few actions behind login walls. Currently doing this with a little JS, adding an event listener and then remote submitting a login modal, and in the _login-success.js.erb I'm calling the event listener.

However, we have options for social media logins (Facebook, Twitter, Google) and this is proving to be difficult to handle.

How do I "suspend" or "interrupt" the user action (Favourite a resource, submitting a review, upvoting a review) to perform the Oauth login and then continue with the action.

User flow I'm looking for is

```
User - Click's "vote" 
(Login Modal Appears)
User - Oauth Login
(Either popup or redirect, perform authentication)
(return to page and submit vote associated with logged in user)
```

I can't find anything about interrupting an action to submit Oauth, but my best guess is storing some ID's in a session for a Vote or Favourite, but it gets more complicated with an entire review in the session. That sounds messy and wrong.

Can someone help guide me as to whether this is even possible? and possibly some resources as to how?